# split string and store it in different variable in C

Tags: c

I want to split this string

> kim-tae-yeon

and put them into different variables, like this:

> data[1] = "kim" data[2] = "tae" data[3] = "yeon"

but I only split the string without store them to these variable.
How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
  char buff[] = "kim-tae-yeon";
  int i = 0;

  char *p = strtok (buff, "-");
  char *data[3];

  while (p)
    {
      data[i++] = p;
      p = strtok (NULL, "-");
    }

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      printf ("%s\n", &data[i]);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on warnings, `-Wall`, and it will show you the problem. Also, do you mean to modify `buff`? Because now it's just `kim`.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Your program works well. The error comes by the fact that you are passing to `printf` `&data[i]` but `data`is an array of pointers (`char *[]`), which means each entry of the array is a pointer (`char *`). You want pass to `printf` a string, `data[i]`.

This is the output you want:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("data[%i] = %s\n", i+1, data[i]);
}
```

As in the comment were said, there is no `data[3]`.
The array starts at `data[0]`, this is a default of C.
You can still have the output

```
data[1] = kim
data[2] = tae
data[3] = yaeon
```

by adding 1 to `i`,
but this output doesn't represent your actual `data` array.

Comment: i already change to your suggestion, still.. its only print
kim,
tae,
yeon.
when i want
data [1] = kim
data [2] = tae
data [3] = yeon

Comment: You mean you want to print: data[1] = kim data[2] = tae data[3] = yeon?

Comment: @user6318361 please let us know what __exactly__ you expect your program to print.

Comment: yes, i want to print exactly like @LotoLo said. so, kim is belong to variable called data[1], tae belong to variable called data[2], and yeon belong to variable called data[3]. thats what i want.

Comment: @user6318361 why didn't you tell us this in the question: You should have written something like: `I want my program to print this....`.

Comment: i thought i already explain what i need in my question, but ill tell more detail in the future question

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
printf("%s\n", &data[i]);
```

The `%s`format specifier requires a `char*` but you provided a `char **`(pointer to pointer to char). `data[i]` *is* already a `char *`, therefore you need:

```
printf("%s\n", data[i]);
```

If you had compiled with all warnings enabled (`-Wall` option with gcc) your compile would have told you this.

Comment: i already change to your suggestion, still.. its only print
kim,
tae,
yeon.
when i want
data [1] = kim
data [2] = tae
data [3] = yeon

Comment: @user6318361 the code works as expected here: http://ideone.com/I424xr. Please edit your question and let us know what output _exactly_ you expect. BTW arrays start with index 0, not 1.

Comment: all i want is split this"kim-tae-yeon" thing, and after it separated, i want to store it to those variable. the variable is data[1], data[2], and data[3].

Comment: @user6318361 Array indexes start at 0. It should be `data[0]`, `data[1]`, and `data[2]`. There is no `data[3]`.

Comment: As it is a standard to start the index of array from 0 ...but if you want you can customized it by starting it with 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're ready to limit the length of the substrings, this can be solved much easier and less scary (`strtok()` is scary, come on!) using plain old `sscanf()`:

```
const char buff[] = "kim-tae-yeon";
char data[3][32];

if (sscanf(buff, "%31[^-]-%31[^-]-%31[^-]", data[0], data[1], data[2]) == 3)
{
  printf("parts are '%s', '%s' and '%s'\n", data[0], data[1], data[2]);
}
```

The format specifier, which is repeated three times with dashes in-between, is `%31[^-]`, this means "collect at most 31 non-dash characters". The 31 makes sure there's room to terminate in our 32-character buffers.

It's a bit non-DRY with the buffer size repeated in the format string, the easiest fix for this is to generate the format string at run-time using `snprintf()`, but that obscures the issue so I didn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can work. It instead uses [`strcpy`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) to copy over the string being pointed at, in this case `buffer`, to the space in `data[i]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRSIZE 50
#define NUMWORDS 3

int
main(void) {
    char buff[] = "kim-tae-yeon";
    char data[NUMWORDS][STRSIZE];
    char *buffer;
    int i;

    buffer = strtok(buff, "-");

    i = 0;
    while (buffer != NULL) {
        strcpy(data[i], buffer);

        printf("data[%i] = %s\n", i+1, data[i]);

        buffer = strtok(NULL, "-");

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```